# Additional validation after core login is success

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, authentication, joomla-3.5

My requirement is to do an additional custom validation once the users core joomla credentials are validated. If my custom validation fails then I should not allow the user to login.

I see there are only 2 plugin methods I can make use of it.

**onUserLogin**

This method will be called only after a successful login which is fine.  If I return false it still allows the user to login to the website.  I tried `JFactory::getApplication()->logout();` but it still allows the user to login.

**onUserAuthenticate**

If I go via this route then I have to implement the whole authentication functionality on my own. (something like copy the core joomla authentication plugin and add my own code)

Is there a simplest way? I.e, once the core joomla authentication is complete I have to do an additional validation and if fails do not allow the member to login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is another event you can perfectly use for this case.

It's `onUserAfterLogin` which gets called right after successful user login (core joomla authentication is complete). See [source](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3b1562b3b17fabd1688c6805c6170c1090280cb6/libraries/legacy/application/application.php#L699).

Then in this event, run your logic and simply call `JFactory::getApplication()->logout();` if it fails. Just like you wanted it.